# PHP constant member variable

Tags: php, oop

I'm looking for a way to declare a member variable that cannot change once initialized (it can be set once, but never reset).

I am not looking for a class constant but a per-instance member variable. Is there anyway to do this in PHP?

Comment: Make a Private class variable, assign the value in constructor, don't change it in the class anywhere, and don't make any mutator (set) function for it.

Comment: @zzlalani I am using more or less doing what you suggested right now. But it doesn't feel robust. I am looking for a PHP construct to restrict the variable from changing more than once, but I guess if it doesn't exist then I am out of luck.

Comment: If you don't change, it won't change, If you write a code in a way no one can change, no one can change it.. lol..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be:

```
class SuperClass {

    private $_something;

    public final SetSomething(SomethingCls $something) {
        if ($this->_something != NULL) {
            throw new \Exception();
        }

        $this->_something = $something;
    }

    public final GetSomething() {
        return $this->_something;
    }

}
```

The fact is there isn't any PHP construct to achive this so you have to write your own implementation to solve the specific problem. You can not protect a variable from overwriting without having some checking and/or protecting by inheritance.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) keyword:-

```
final $variable
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or providing an answer? This should really be a comment.

Comment: If I was only making a comment I would put it in the comment field.

Comment: Your wording makes it look like a question.

Comment: No, but "Why can't you" implies a question. There is no construct in English where a sentence starting with those words wouldn't be a question. Whereas "You could do" would be an answer.

Comment: Note: Properties cannot be declared final, only classes and methods may be declared as final.